# how To have military police see a lot of combat

Tags: military

What would be a plausible reason to have your average military police officer see a lot of combat

Thanks for your time

Comment: You thank us for the time we invest. Yet what time did you invest?

Comment: Hi user55930, this looks like a very open ended question and I'm VTCing as too Opinion based Don't be disheartened. Police officers are there to protect civilians and are not soldiers or a part of the army. If there are many violent gang crimes in the area they will of course see more combat, but it won't be the same as military combat. Police just aren't trained the same way a soldier is. Please remember this is not an idea generation website, we don't want to do your work for you. If you want police to see more combat, increase the crimes that have combat.

Comment: You send the not-trained-for-combat soldiers into combat when all the trained-for-combat soldiers are in combat and you need more soldiers sooner than new recruits can be trained.

Comment: The only channel on the police station TV only shows UFC and MMA matches 24/7.

Comment: Please, do not repost questions that were poorly received: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/126653/809 Edit them instead.

Comment: @Shadowzee OP specified **Military** Police, not regular police.

Comment: Google 2nd MP Battalion (Marines) or in fact any of the field MP units of the military - they're all combat units

Comment: User5590 might I suggest you post a question on the History Beta and ask about instances when Military Police units became involved in heavy combat, this might spark some ideas in your head.

Comment: NATO doctrine has MPs (among others) protecting logistic convoys and trains, ports, railheads, movement control points, and other nodes...in addition to their other duties. Write a deep battlefield where these nodes see enough action to meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

> "From 9 March to 17 March members of the 9th Military Police Company
>   were positioned at both ends and all along the bridge to guide a
>   steady stream of POWs, vehicles, and troops. Other MPs were detailed
>   as snipers to watch for German frogmen who might attempt to blow up
>   the bridge. When a vehicle was hit or the driver wounded, they helped
>   get the vehicle off the bridge, even if it meant driving it. They
>   manned aid stations and POW cages on both shores, and they installed
>   and maintained wire communications across the bridge, all while under
>   artillery fire.[126] The Meritorious Unit Citation, the Belgian
>   Fourragère, The 9th Military Police Platoon was recognized the
>   Presidential Unit Citation for its performance at the Ludendorff
>   Bridge.[127][128]:44 1st LT John Hyde of the 9th Military Police
>   Company was Bridge Control Officer. Hyde had famously denied General
>   George Patton passage through a roadblock over the general's vigorous
>   objections earlier in the war.[129][130] Hyde implemented established
>   rigid traffic patterns to maintain a constant flow of vehicles and
>   troops for more than 15 days. Hyde received a Silver Star for his
>   bravery and gallantry under fire at the Ludendorff Bridge.[64]"

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Remagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Remagen#%22Dead_Man's_Corner%22)